# Websites not working on IOS after server move (only affecting sites with SSL)

Tags: https, safari, lets-encrypt, ios

I'm most of the way through moving from one server to another. Servers are more or less the same, newer one has a newer version of Plesk.

Everything has gone very smoothly BUT now I check on Safari or Chrome on IOS none of the sites running SSL are working. (I use Lets Encrypt).

I thought this might be a local problem but I just checked Analytics and Safari stats have gone off a cliff for my sites. Other browsers are working fine.
I did see a message briefly along the lines of "unable to parse".

My initial thoughts were that it was a DNS caching issue. My TTLs were set quite high. I figured that even if the site was still up and running on the old server this might cause an issue with the SSL certificate. I've tried to clear the cache on the iPhone but this hasn't helped.

Am at something of a loss as to what to try next.

Comment: Seems to be working if I disable http2 on Apache. Odd because my old server was running this

Comment: Seems to relate to this: https://dev.to/dsofeir/website-not-working-in-any-browser-on-ios-2p4n

Comment: Did you try the recommended solution "remove Protocols h2 from the Apache config"?

Comment: @Steve couldn't find any reference to it in any of the config files. I just disabled the Apache http2 module through the Plesk interface. 
Strangely I have this running fine on the old server. Also, with the http2 mod disabled I still appear to be running HTTP2 when I test it?!